# MongoDB - finding most popular words in collection

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible in MongoDB to extract most popular words from certain field in collection's documents? I read MongoDb Text Search documentation, but i didn't find anything.

I am in the middle of migrating my database from PostgreSQL to MongoDB. 
In PostgreSQL i had full text index (pgsql tsearch) which i was using to  function ts_stat to extract most popular words in stored articles. How to do that in MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you need, but I just wrote a sample code for you, see if it helps. :)

```
var keys=db.collection.distinct('Key');
Array.max = function( array ){
    return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
};
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  keyTrend[i]= db.collection.find({"Key":keys[i]}).count()
}
Array.max(keyTrend)
```

I have not tested the code, but hope it works. As mongodb is all manipulated with javascript, you can always seek help with javascript to suit your customized needs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that example, but i don't think if it is solution. My collection is "articles" with fields: title,content,created_date,category. Title and content are String fields.  Content is very long.  I have text index({"content":text})  on it to speed up search queries. But i don't know if it possible to use this text index to extract most popular words in articles.content...

Comment: I have the same idea in mind @PajakLeon did you eventually found a solution?